# How to return value if point exactly inside polygon in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, polygon, point, mysql-5.7

I want to return value from table where point exactly exist in polygon field
I wrote query but is not accurate, value returned even point be around the polygon

```
"select `name`,`loc_id` FROM `locations` where MBRContains(`polygons`,ST_GeomFromText('Point($loc[0] $loc[1])'))= 1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql  instead of MBR ( minimum bounding rectangle) you should use ST_CONTAINS

```
"select `name`,`loc_id` 
    FROM `locations` 
    where ST_CONTAINS(`polygons`,ST_GeomFromText('Point($loc[0] $loc[1])'))= 1"
```

ST_CONTAINS returns true only if one feature contains the other and due the fact that  your are checking for point so this should give you a better result

Comment: thanks but does not work, for example this polygon  `35.745816   51.22839,35.750552   51.227703,35.748323   51.221008,35.745537   51.221695,35.735993   51.221266,35.731046   51.242294,35.72798   51.253281,35.746234   51.254826,51.254826   51.254654,35.745816   51.22839`     i search for point `35.72798 51.25328` result shows nothing

Comment: this is from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains ... be sure you have proper geometry type ..and value